# connection between sql Server and Php using WAMPServer

Tags: php, sql, wamp

I'm unable to connect sql server using my php cod, i am using 5.6 PHP version
here my connection code

```
<?php
$serverName = "IMMY-PC"; 
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"AdventureWorksDW2014", "UID"=>"xxx", "PWD"=>"xxx");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

in php.in i have added `extension= php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll` and `extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll`

error during connection

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in
C:\wamp64\www\check\const.php on line 4 Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location 
1   0.0010  235560  {main}( )   ...\const.php:0
```

i am new to PHP, please help me

Comment: `PDO` != `sqlsrv_connect`, use PDO. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Comment: Thanks chirs, now i modify my code but still connection is not stabilized, now i getting error 
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in C:\wamp64\www\check\const.php on line 4
( ! ) PDOException: could not find driver in C:\wamp64\www\check\const.php on line 4
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0020 235960 {main}( ) ...\const.php:0
2 0.0020 236672 __construct ( ) ...\const.php:4

Comment: Okay, so sounds like you don't have the PDO driver as well.. which do you have `php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll` or `php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll`

Comment: i mean connection is not done.this piece of code i using now

Comment: i having both driver in my php ext folder and added that extension in php.in

Comment: If you load the php info does it show pdo as being available?

Comment: no i didnt find that in phpinfo(), what wrong i did , can you please help

Comment: Did you restart the apache instance after updating the PHP ini? Are you modifying the correct php ini? I also don't think you want the `nts` and `ts`, it should be one or the other.

Comment: yes i have restart the services ,and i have modify the correct ini file

Comment: WAMPServer requires the ThreadSafe version (TS) the NTS version will not run in WAMPServer so remove all reference to it

Comment: Did you download and install [Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=20098)

Comment: Thank you everyone. it's working now